# Sikuli.RunProject doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, sikuli

I am using `SikuliCSharp` package and trying to run `sikuli` script by calling `Sikuli.RunProject(" path to .sikuli-file")`;

When i run project there are no actions and no exceptions.
What i am doing wrong?
Thanks.